# Cumulative Percent of Total

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

```
 Drug      Item Count   Total Cost  Cost/Item   % Total Cost    Cumulative % Total Cost
 Humalog          10          250   $25.00          6.7%           6.7%
 Novolog          5           100   $20.00          2.7%           9.4%
 Apidra           20          600   $30.00          16.1%          25.5%
 Velosulin        10          800   $80.00          21.5%          47.0%
 Lantus           50         1200   $24.00          32.3%          79.3%
 Levemir          35          770   $22.00          20.7%          100.0%
```

I've got a detail band in iReport that successfully calculates cost per item and percent of total cost -- see mock-up above. For percent of total cost, I take $F{cost}/$V{sum_all_costs}. I'm having a little trouble with cumulative percent of total cost, though. I can get a variable that shows cumulative sum:

```
Name: RUNNING_SUM
Calculation: Sum
Reset type: Report
Increment type: None
Variable Expression: $F{cost}
Evaluation Time: Now <-- when the variable is used in the detail band
```

Any thoughts on how I can take this cumulative sum and get cumulative percentage?

Comment: If I don't understand your question right I'm sorry but... I think cumulative sum / total = cumulative percentage (as a decimal)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "cumulative percentage"?

Comment: Yes - but I have to set an evaluation time for (running sum)/(sum all costs). I'm not sure how to have one text field with an equation where the numerator is evaluated now, and the denominator is evaluated when the report is complete.

Comment: As you iterate through the list, each element's percentage of the total contributes to a cumulative percent of the total. So, above, Humalog is 6.7% and Novolog is 2.7%. In the Novolog row, the cumulative percent of the total is now 9.4%.

Comment: I also don't understand the question correctly. Can you show us what you HAVE and what you NEED to achieve?

Comment: In the database, I have drug, item count, and total cost. In iReport I am calculating cost per item and percent of total cost (row-level). So - that's what I have. I also need to calculate the cumulative percent of total cost.

Comment: if you don't have all the information you can't have a total cost field you can have a running total but you can't use information you don't have.  Again, I don't fully understand the question but you can either evaluate it all at the end after you have the total or you can evaluate it as a running total and update previous rows with each pass if they aren't automatically updated for you.  It depends on your specific application engine.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'll just try to bring in a running subtotal using my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the running total is simple (as you demonstrated in the question). The problem with a running percentage is that you need to know the total first. As you point out, conceptually you need to evaluate the denominator later. But there's no way to specify that.

When I did this in the past I did it like this: Treat your entire current report as a subreport. The only change needed in the report is to add a parameter called $P{GrandTotal}. Then create a brand new report that re-uses the same query. It calculates the GrandTotal and passes it to the subreport. The master report doesn't really need any display elements at all. Now that the subreport has the total as a parameter you can do your running percentage as `$F{RUNNING_SUM} / $P{GrandTotal}`.

Note: The main report doesn't really need to run exactly the same query. It will probably make sense to use a modified query which calculates the total in the database. As long as it calculates the total somehow you're all set.